# Creating a List of like Indicies

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, nested

new here and somewhat new to Python. I am having a blank and would appreciate some guidance.

I am trying to write a nested list, then write a for loop to print a comma seperated list of the numbers using like indicies from each list to pair-up the numbers. I have my code below(2.7.14):

```
FirstNumbers = [1, 2, 3]
SecondNumbers = [4, 5, 6]
ThirdNumbers = [7, 8, 9]
NestedNumbers = [FirstNumbers, SecondNumbers, ThirdNumbers]
for i in range(0, 3):
    for each_number in NestedNumbers:
            print each_number[i],
#Output
```

`1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9`

My current issue is trying to get the numbers to read [1, 4, 7] and so on. I would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you

Comment: looks like a homework..! or quiz or assignment, neh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need empty list so you can append the numbers to that i.e

```
FirstNumbers = [1, 2, 3]
SecondNumbers = [4, 5, 6]
ThirdNumbers = [7, 8, 9]
NestedNumbers = [FirstNumbers, SecondNumbers, ThirdNumbers]
m = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    k = []
    for each_number in NestedNumbers:
        k.append(each_number[i])
    m.append(k)
```

Output m : `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`

Comment: Huge help, while I didn't use your exact code, it gave me the basis for figuring it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "print "[" after "for i in range(0,3)" and a print "]" after the "for each_number" part 
so that it will print:
[1 4 7][2 5 8][3 6 9]
Now you need to insert a print ", " before "print each_number[i]"
You will end up with:
[, 1, 4, 7][, 2, 5, 8][, 3, 6, 9] You need to not use print ", " on the first run-through as that is printing the comma before the first number.

You will need to change the second for statement to not go through "NestedNumbers" because you cannot know if it is the first one, but instead "range(0,len(NestedNumbers))" so that you can check to see if it is the first iteration and whether you need to add a comma.
change it to:

```
FirstNumbers = [1, 2, 3]
SecondNumbers = [4, 5, 6]
ThirdNumbers = [7, 8, 9]
NestedNumbers = [FirstNumbers, SecondNumbers, ThirdNumbers]
for x in range(0,3): 
    print "["
    for y in range(0,len(NestedNumbers)):
       if y!=0: print ", "
       print NestedNumbers[y][i]
    print "]"
```

Now it will print:

[1, 4, 7][2, 5, 8][3, 6, 9]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import itertools
for n in itertools.chain(*zip(FirstNumbers,SecondNumbers,ThirdNumbers))
    print n,
```

The call to `zip` combines the lists as you want as a list of tuples. Then `itertools.chain` flattens this to a single list.

if you actually want this output:

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Just print the result of calling `zip`